# Is 6 kHz bandpass filter wide enough for listening to SW broadcasts?

Tags: filter, audio, swl

I'm considering buying ICOM IC-718 as a main rig and also to use it for SWL. Read contrasting opinions on the Internet, with an article reviewing dedicated SW receivers saying *"That receiver's widest filter setting is 9 kHz, not so bad but kinda meh."*

So if they say 9 kHz is nothing special, then how about IC-718's 6 kHz?..

Comment: As radio designer of antique equipment (in that days, yes) I can add this (for AM): the -3 dB BW of a low-order filter can still give good audio beyond the specified cut-off frequency. With very steep filters the selectivity is better and the audio response is "less friendly". Radio BW for noise was 3 kHz and despite the plus and minus 1.5 kHz pass band the audio tone control allowed still satisfactory music reproduction. So when it is a DSP-filter it must be a higher bandwidth. IMHO.

Comment: The answers might fall into the range of opinion.  Try it with an SDR where you can set the bandwidth, listen to some AM stations, and see whether you yourself think 6kHz versus 9kHz versus 15kHz makes much of a diff to you and how much diff is "enough".  For you.

Comment: Thank you @F.Sessink, that's very interesting and helpful! From what I understand, IC-718 doesn't use DSP for filtering, it's all analogue and DSP is an optional module for noise reduction / notch.

Comment: Gotcha @hotpaw2. Thanks for the advice... although I don't want to touch SDR or anything digital, even for testing ;) Old school is cool!